# How much does it cost to repair an Enigma armor?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I would like to know the repair costs of an Enigma rune word in the following armors:

- [Mage Plate](https://diablo2.io/base/mage-plate-t1404.html)
- [Dusk Shroud](https://diablo2.io/base/dusk-shroud-t1390.html)
- [Archon Plate](https://diablo2.io/base/archon-plate-t1405.html)

#### Update

I did some tests with less expensive rune words.

##### Exceptional Dusk Shroud

1 point durability costs 19712.

[image: Exeptional Dusk Shroud]

##### Exceptional Great Hauberk

1 point durability costs 22784.

[image: Exceptional Great Hauberk]

Comment: It should be `cost = item_value * (max_dur/dur) / 8`, and item_value is affected by the stats/modifiers/charges/quality an item has. I'm not posting this as an answer since I can't find a valid source.